# HTML placing navigation bar above my chatbot

Tags: html, css

How do i allocate my navigation bar above to my chatbot?

css file "navigation bar css" this is just some part of the code

```
 *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body{
    font-family: montserrat;
  }
  nav{
    position: fixed;
    background: #0082e6;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;

  }
  label.logo{
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
```

This is my HTML section for navigation

```
<nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check">
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <label class="logo">DesignX</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

Its seem like the navigation bar is overlapping the chatbot menu.

[image]

Comment: You can use `z-index` if you create a snippet i will correct you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-top` on `body`

your `navigation` is `fixed`

```
body{
    font-family: montserrat;
    padding-top:80px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. by doing z-index and padding-top into my css navigation . I manage to make it fit nicely

Answer (score 0):

Please use z-index: 1; in the nav class!!!